# How to identify the list of images for the particular subscription id is accessible in azure

Tags: powershell, azure

I am able to get the list of images for the particular subscription id using this command.

```
Get-AzureVMImage | Where-Object {($_.Label -ne $null) -and
($_.Label.Contains('2012 R2')) -and
($_.PublisherName.Contains("Microsoft Windows Server Group"))} |
Sort-Object PublishedDate[-1]
```

If suppose the obtained image cannot be accessed and throws error as `Forbidden error`.